# React Calender Library

Tags: reactjs, calendar

I have to build the exact calender in reactjs and use api's data to show a circular bar on each date. Any idea how should I do this or any library you can suggest. Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question you can do following. Check if it helps you...
 1. Use React Datepicker

2. UI matches can be done with CSS playing
3. if you wish ot highlight any dates  then first check what is your formula to mark few dates as highlighted
4. Take a look at documentation : https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-highlight-dates
5. Refer to "Highlight dates" and "Highlight dates with custom class names and ranges" option
6. Check below area from link

   [image]

Comment: I dont think this will work. Can you suggest any other thing